# Show and hide element when URL contains certain section of text?

Tags: jquery, javascript

I require #nav1 to display and #nav2 to hide on all pages which include "/category-1/" in the URL.

I require #nav2 to display and #nav1 to hide on all pages which include "/category-2/" in the URL.

I have this code:

```
    <script>  

var url = window.location.href;

if (url.indexOf("/category-1/") > -1)
{
    document.getElementById('#nav1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('#nav2').style.display = 'true';
}

else if (url.indexOf("/category-2/") > -1)
{
    document.getElementById('#nav2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('#nav1').style.display = 'true';
}

</script>
```

But it appears to be having no effect.

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

`true` is not a valid value for `display` in CSS. You either need to use one of the [valid values for the display property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) or an empty string to remove the style override.

If both menus are  styled to display by default then you'd just be better off adding and removing `display: none;`, rather than setting a specific value when its displayed:

```
if (url.indexOf("/category-1/") > -1)
{
    document.getElementById('#nav1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('#nav2').style.display = '';
}

else if (url.indexOf("/category-2/") > -1)
{
    document.getElementById('#nav2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('#nav1').style.display = '';
}
```

If you have control over your theme's templates though, you'd probably be better off hiding and showing the correct nav in the template. You can use `is_category()` to check if you're viewing a specific category archive, or `has_category()` to check if the current post has that category:

```
<?php if ( is_category( 'category-1' ) || ( is_single() && has_category( 'category-1', get_queried_object() ) ) ) : ?>
    <nav id="nav1"></nav>
<?php elseif ( is_category( 'category-2' ) || ( is_single() && has_category( 'category-2', get_queried_object() ) ) ) : ?>
    <nav id="nav2"></nav>
<?php endif; ?>
```